# When is the post office close?

Tags: questions

Is it well?

> When is the post office close?
>   What time the post office close?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *What time (or, when) does the post office close?* is correct. So is, *Is the post office open or closed?* But not, *when is it close?*

Comment: ...When it's less than a mile from your house.

Comment: When does the post office close? What time does the post office close? The answer varies by [location](https://tools.usps.com/go/POLocatorAction!input.action).

Answer (score 1):

In the US the common way of saying this would be:

> What time does the post office open/close?

If you are talking to the guy on the phone, then I think you can say:

> What time do you guys close?

This is the simple present and you need to use do/does for questions with main verbs other than *to be(is, am, are).*

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences will be written like that:-

When is the post office closed?

What time do they close the post office?

Answer (score 1):

> **When** does the post office close?
>
> The post office closes **Saturdays at 12 noon**.

**When** is the post office closed?

The post office is closed **Saturday afternoons and Sundays**.

> **What time** does the post office close?
>
> The post office closes **at 5PM**.